# Is there a Solr collection API available for listing solr alias

Tags: solr, solrj

I am trying to list certain collections only based on the wildcard.

Is there any Solr collection API available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible, the only API call available right now for Solr is to list all collections by doing something like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=LIST&wt=json
```

For more information -https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-List

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply, Currently I using the above mentioned list api, Can you suggest how i can query solr to list me some particular ten collections out of hundred